# Turbo boost technology drives gives error code 10

Tags: windows-7, drivers, device-manager, intel-core-i5

I have system with :

Core i5 670 3.6 GHz,
8 GB RAM,
Windows 7 Ultimate

My device manager shows turbo boost technology driver unhealthy and in property it gives message : this driver cannot start (Code 10)

Kindly let know the probable reason or solutions please.

Comment: Has it ever worked in the past?

Comment: Have you searched online? One this site, you should always Google before asking.

Comment: Ya i have searched but not finding anything exactly matching to mine problem.